# MKMapView does not change region

Tags: ios, mkmapview, zooming, segue, region

I have an app where I have a table and after clicking on a cell, the nav controller segues to a MKMapView. I wanna set the region of the map manually so the user sees a zoomed view over a particular area. To do that, in viewWillAppear i do :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.345305, -6.2721597);
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 3000, 3000);
self.map.region = region;
```

The thing is, the first time around I segue to a map view, it seems to have no effect what so ever on a map. Its only when I go back to the the table view, and segue to the map again, the MKMapView actually moves to a given co-ord and zooms in. Has anyone ever encountered such strange behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that viewWillAppear is too early in the process for the map to be ready? Try moving your code to viewDidAppear and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `viewWillAppear`

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.345305, -6.2721597);
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 3000, 3000);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.map regionThatFits:region];  
[self.map setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

Comment: No luck, the exact same behaviour :(